# How to install Windows 7 after removing Windows 10?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ntfs, windows-10-preview

After [this problem](https://superuser.com/q/880867/162573) (not being able to mount ntfs drives in Linux after installation of Windows 10 because of hybrid shutdown technology) **I have deleted both Windows/ntfs partitions and created new ones under Linux with gparted. But I have done that before doing a proper shutdown in Windows 10 TP, basically while Windows 10 was in a hibernation state.**

Now I want to install Windows 7 in one o the new ntfs partitions but at the end of the installation I get a restart - sometimes with a blue screen crash message about the drive being corrupt or something - and then the message that the installation was interrupted and needs to be re-initiated.

Also, I tried to let Windows7 re-format the installation partition and create a reserved partition too, and that worked normally. But the same error occurred.

I tried the same with both x64 and x32 versions of Win7, the same result, also installed from initial DVD in Virtualbox to test that the DVD/image was ok.

The partition table looks like this in gnome-disk-utility:

[image]

I think Windows 10 has left something on the drive that results in this, maybe related to a rescue session or the hybrid shutdown technology. Could it be this? Could this affect the whole partition table or just the ntfs partitions (involved in the linked question)?

How to remove or be sure there are no such remains?

---

UPDATE:

Following this solution on [How To Fix A Corrupted Windows NTFS Filesystem With Ubuntu](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/) I got no results.

I have re-installed Window 10 TP without any problems.

Comment: Why are you not allowing Windows to create the NTFS partition?  If you deleted the partitions then you have already removed Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound - sorry, I will edit: I have removed windows 10 but then I wanted to install Windows 7 and cannot. I have formatted with Windows 7 those partitions with the same result. I am afraid that Win 8.1 / 10 technology  involves installing something in the partition table or something that remains after deleting the partitions.

Comment: The only possible thing it could be is that `Partition 1` but I suspect this is connected to the installation media not being booted in EFI mode.

Comment: Indeed, Windows could leave something (MBR or EFI loader), but most OS installers do that and it wouldn't interrupt the installer. Which kind of partition table is this: MBR or GPT?

Comment: @gronostaj - It was created with Gparted in Linux, it's the default option, 'msdos'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in installing Windows 7, in this way:

- I have **re-installed Windows 10 back into a 30GB partition**, formatted it, which created a supplementary reserved 100 MB partition.
- I have created a new 50 GB partition out o the big 160 GB space and left the rest unpartitioned because I had reached the maximum of 4 primary partitions. I **installed Windows 7 in this new ntfs partition** without the previous problem, and I guess it has replaced the 100 MB reserved with its own.
- I have **repaired grub2 with Boot Repair in Linux**. Now there was one Windows entry in the grub, and after selecting it there were two entries to choose between Win 7 and Win 10. This menu was not the new Win8-style one, but the old Win7-style.

(Now I had 4 primary partitions already: one the reserved bootloader partition, second the Win10, third the Win7 and fourth the extended one containing multipe linuxes. Between the latter and the rest a big chunk of un-partitioned space: in order to be able to use it I had to delete a partition. I didn't wanted it inside the Win7 partition. Adding it as a separate logical partition inside the extended one would have possibly made it inaccessible from Windows.)

- I **deleted both the reserved partition and the Win10 partition.** (This made the Win7 system invisible even after updating grub. Reinstalling grub or restoring MBR with grub-repair didn't work.)

(Before trying to fix this, using Gparted in Linux, I have moved the Windows partition to the extreme left and unified the empty space in which I created one big ntfs partition.)

- **Booted in the Windows 7 installation DVD**, chose Repair installation. It didn't see the Windows 7 installation, but when looking for restore image/drivers it was able to see the partition. Choosing repair started a process that seemed endless, I interrupted it. But upon rebooting again in the Windows 7 installation DVD, the installation was found. Repair seemed to work but rebooting went directly into the grub list (without Windows listed there of course). At this point I might have tried update-grub in Linux but before that I booted again in the Win7 DVD and **choosing Command prompt I used this command: `bootrec /fixboot`.**
- Booted normally in Linux, **updated grub and Windows 7 was added to the boot list**.