# How to access files on Windows from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, file-sharing

I have a laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to access my files on Windows from Ubuntu, but it turns out that I could only do this when I restarted the Windows system before booting Ubuntu, which means, if I wanted to access my files on Windows, I had to first boot Windows, restart, and then boot Ubuntu. Is this normal? Or is there any way I can access files without completing this process every time? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome at Superuser! One option would be to create another partition, which is neither your Windows Boot partition nor your Ubuntu Boot partition. On that partition you can store all your data and access it from both OSs. If you want to access your Windows Boot partition (commonly C:) you need to shut down Windows completely. Modern Windows Versions (8 and 10) do not completely shut down, when you tell them to shut down. It is a hybrid state similation to hypernation. However, if you do a reboot under Windows it shuts down completely for the reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have the same problem you are describing when I used Windows 10 together with my linux system.

Then I found the an explanation of How-to-geek website that helped me to solve my problem. [See if this helps you to solve yours.](http://www.howtogeek.com/236807/how-to-mount-your-windows-10-or-8-system-drive-on-linux/)

Or maybe [this Superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/880867/cannot-mount-ntfs-partitions-because-of-windows-10) can help you as it talks about a similar situation. Or this [AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation). Well, there are plenty of explanations online describing the solution of your problem. Some of them are in the these links.

If your problem is the same that I had (being bored to sometimes of when accessing ubuntu have that annoyed message saying you can't access your windows partitions), I solved that by doing a complete shutdown on Windows 10 instead of letting it to do its default shutdown, that now is a kind of  hybrid shutdown, which is basically a logoff + hibernation. I learned the solution on the links above.

About disabling Windows hibernation there are too many sources on the internet showing how to do it. The one I used was open an elevated command prompt, that one with administrative rights that is like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

and then I typed the command:

```
powercfg -h off
```

and then type ENTER on the keyboard.

The command will be like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -h off
```

There is other forms to do that if you can. Like I said in the beginning of the post, recommending you some other links on the web, if you search a little on the internet you can easily find deep discussion involving the solution of your problem. But basically from what I understood of your description, what I showed here can help you as well.

I hope I had helped you.

PS: Just in case you regret to have disabled hibernation (learn what if does and decide if you want to keep it of not on your Windows 10. It's not extremely necessary to keep it, but some people like for personal preferences) the command to re-enable hibernation by elevated command prompt is this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -h on
```

Comment: You must also disable Windows hibernation. Ubuntu is "smart" enough to recognize the presence of hiberfil.sys and to refuse write access to the Windows partition to protect data stored there.

Comment: @Dan We expect answers to contain the actual solution.  This means going into specifics.  You can do this in combination of quoting and citing relevant links, or use your actual knowledge, to generate your unique content.  If you find yourself quoting existing Superuser questions answer, it might be better, to flag the question as a duplicate of the question with an existing answer if you feel the existing answer answers this question

Comment: @Ramhound Ok. I am new to superuser so I am getting used on how to make a good answer. But I got the point, that I can refer to links but need to show some details here too. Besides that, I thanks for the observation and while you commented I was already detailing the answer. See if its better now.

Comment: My comment isn't really the type you reply to. Just improve your answer I routinely go back through my votes daily.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called SAMBA - You can read more about it on this [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software))

> Samba allows file and print sharing between computers running Microsoft Windows and computers running Unix

I'm not going to go into detail on how to configure it because it's a long time since I used it myself. I am however certain that this is what you're looking for.